# bash script - remove rows and decrement column values

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I have file with 3 columns:

```
9 1 2
2 2 1
5 3 1
7 3 1
5 3 1
2 3 1
8   2 1
3 2 1
1 1 1
```

I want to remove from the first column particular values and the relative rows, for example 2 and 5 (that are present more times in the same column) and decrement all the values in the first column that are greater than that value.
So if I remove first the number 2 I want to obtain:

```
8 1 2

4 3 1
6 3 1
4 3 1

7 2 1
2 2 1
1 1 1
```

and then 5(that now is 4) my output would be:

```
7 1 2


5 3 1


6 2 1
2 2 1
1 1 1
```

How can I do that? Consider that I have to remove lot of values in the real case and the file is really big.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How do you decide which rows to remove and why? Can you expand your explanation a little more?

Comment: So the file with the 3 columns is a sparse matrix and the first column are coordinates.  I have to remove around 60 values that correspond to particular coordinates of the first column but I want also to remove the corresponding rows and keep the remaining coordinates. If the remaining coordinates are greater than the value (2 as the example) I want to reduce that coordinates  value of the first column of  1.

Comment: @shiva, is it mandatory to retain empty lines?

Comment: No I don't want empty lines. I add them only for clarity of the example.

Comment: what if you had 3 lines with first column in 2 instead of having two lines? it should delete only lines with first column==2 (the lines with maximum first column repeated)? or delete until no lines with duplicated first column and recursively repeat the action?

Comment: It should delete the line every time there is the occurrence of 2 but the decrease of the values > 2 is only once.

Comment: How are the lines chosen as to which are deleted?

Comment: I have a fixed list of values that I have to remove from the file.

Comment: will you be feeding the file into a script, or running commands? I ask because it changes whether it will be a function and script, or a series of commands. (May not seem like much of a difference, but something like awk '{ print $1 }' would be handled differently between the two answers

Comment: Its the same. Both script and running commands are ok.

Answer (score 0):

**`bash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
i=0;
for n in 2 5; do
    awk -v n="$n" -v iter=$((++i)) \
   'iter == 1{ 
        if ($1 > n) { $1-- } else if ($1 == n) { next }
    }
    iter > 1{
        if ($1 + 1 == n){ next } else if ($1 >= n) $1-- 
    }1' inp_file > tmp_inpfile && mv tmp_inpfile inp_file
done
```

The final `inp_file` contents:

```
7 1 2
5 3 1
6 2 1
2 2 1
1 1 1
```

Comment: can you please explain the code? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you to test this approach on different values in different order. And if it fails in some critical cases - I would rather delete this answer.